# You can stay here if you like

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal, can-modal

1. *You **can** roast chicken whole or in pieces if you want to/if you like.*
2. *You **could** roast chicken whole or in pieces if you want to/if you like*.
3. *You **can** stay here if you like*.

Q1) Does sentence (1) sound like a suggestion to someone, or does it sound like a statement conveying information, or like a statement used for stating a fact about "chicken"?

Q2) Does sentence (2) sound like a suggestion to someone?

Q3) Does sentence (3) sound like a suggestion or an offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentences are fine with either can or could. Both would be understood as a suggestion because of the context. It's fairly common to use can/could as synonyms in informal English, especially when the context makes the meaning clear.

However, "roast chicken whole or in pieces" sounds a bit odd to my British ears. It's not wrong and can be understood, but it's not something I would say. It sounds non-native. There's a term for chicken which has been cut up into pieces: you can say *chicken joints/jointed chicken.*

Suggested edit

> You can/could roast a whole or jointed chicken if you want/if you like.

Comment: Not disagreeing with your jointed Chicken for most Western Cultures. However the majority of the worlds population does not eat jointed Chicken they eat, literally, pieces of Chicken. With the UK being a cosmopolitan society now, it would also apply to some Native UK English speakers.

Comment: @Billy, can I **also** use sentence (1) to state a fact about "chicken", just like the passive voice sentence: "chicken **can** be roasted whole or in pieces"?

Comment: @Mr X, yes of course.

Comment: @Brad I didn't say there's anything wrong here.  It's the "chicken ... in pieces" that sounds odd to me, not "pieces of chicken" which is fine too.

Comment: @Billy Kerr I was not criticising just point out the fact. I dream of jointed chicken unfortunately where I live ATM they don't have it. Just chopped up Chuck with the skin still on.

Comment: @Brad - eh . . . in the UK, "chuck" is a kind of steak (from a cow), not a chicken.

Comment: Yes you are correct my spelling is abysmal! Chook! But regarding your comment; How to keep up with globalisation? EVEN cows and chickens are being Americanised and we cannot blame Hollywood for that, can we? Chuck steak Never! Chuck and Blade I may be forced (kicking & screaming) to accept. Maybe the Brexit boys can help me?.. I digress ...Surely you mean "Braising Steak" or “Flatiron Steak,”. Commonly know as shoulder also called Blade steak”.  Used in casseroles, stews and to braise. Try this link for British Beef. Not a Chuck Steak in sight https://www.thedoodales.co.uk/cuts-of-beef/ .

Comment: @Brad you may wish to refer to this rather nice [diagram of beef cuts](https://www.morleybutchers.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/beef_cuts_poster.jpg) prepared by the English Beef and Lamb Executive, which is part of the United Kingdom Meat and Livestock Commission.

Comment: @Brad - also it's quite possible to joint a chicken yourself. There's a good video here: https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/techniques/jointing_chicken

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the gesture. And yes I do a lot of my own stuff. Simple stuff like making gravy from basics to my own Bread, cakes, suet dumpling etc etc. getting the right cuts of meat can be rather risky at times though. Also getting the ingredients can be a momentous task . But the chickens! Killing, bleeding and de-feathering gutting and skinning is not my forte. Especially with the twins helping me.  Plus I hate the smell they make in the car. Call me a wimp I don't care!